# Not able to open BTC Wallet

Tags: recover-private-key, lost-wallet

My friend lost his PRIVATE Keys. Any way we can still retrieve the BTC Wallet? No other info can be provided only BTC Address.

Answer (score 3):

No, private keys are randomly picked from the space of 256-bit numbers. A private key cannot be recovered from the address, otherwise anyone could take any other user's funds at will. If your friend doesn't have additional information such as e.g. a set of seed words, or a backup, it is infeasible to rediscover the private key.